# Customize Linux ping icmp response

Tags: linux, networking, ping, icmp

Is there any way to customize the icmp echo response a Linux machine sends back when someone pings it? Say I ping my PC at home and I want it to send a few bytes of preset data back, a message in ASCII for example. I know that I can send data to someone through the ping command with the -p option and that it just sends that same data back, so I guess it is possible to somehow customize the data, only how?

I do know C++ so I can program an icmp client if necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initially wrote that you could not do it, but then, Googling around, I found [this link](http://ttps://books.google.com/books?id=s7f84QCM3TsC&pg=PA228&lpg=PA228&dq=icmp%20response%20carrying%20data&source=bl&ots=jd03Nt06tY&sig=Iem8eRxxh9sFLmWO79RFPY5Hy-k&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=icmp%20response%20carrying%20data&f=false). It mentions a program, [Loki](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?4768-Installing-loki-on-kali-linux-amd64), which does exactly what you propose, but apparently in  more mischevious ways than you originally considered. The `deb` package mentioned above does not include source code, but you can find that [here](http://www.packetstan.com/2011/02/running-loki-on-backtrack-4-r2.html).

I will be studying it as you read this.

Comment: Thank you very much. Im still struggling with some python issues though. I really dont like python and my PC seems to have the same opinion. So I'm editing the code so it runs correctly, cause it seems to be written for python 3 whereas im running 2 even though 3 is installed as well. But oh well, I'll get it to work somehow, or I'll just run kali in a VM